# Healthcheck for questdb docker-compose image

Tags: questdb

How can we do healthcheck for docker compose setup for Questdb.

The default image does not have `ps`, `nc`, `wget`, `curl` or `pgrep`.

Is there any easy way to do a check or this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was fun to reply :)

First make sure you are starting the container with the health check and metrics (if needed) endpoints enabled passing the env variables, as in:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 9003:9003 -e QDB_METRICS_ENABLED=true -e QDB_HTTP_MIN_ENABLED=true questdb/questdb:latest
```

You don't actually need to expose port 9003 if you want to test only from inside docker.

Now, how can you test from the same container with no curl or wget? I tried with java, which is available on the /application/bin folder of the image, but no java compiler there.

But it turns out we have Perl, so you can do:

```
perl -e 'use IO::Socket::INET; $|=1; $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>"localhost:9003"); print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: localhost:9003\r\n\r\n"; while(<$socket>) { print $_; }'
```

You should get the output of the healtcheck

[image]

If you want the full metrics, just use `localhost:9003/metrics instead`

And if you wanted just `exit(0)` or `exit(1)` depending on status you could do something similar to

```
perl -e 'use IO::Socket::INET; $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>"localhost:9003") or exit 1; print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: localhost:9003 \r\n\r\n"; $response = <$socket>; if ($response =~ /HTTP\/1\.[01] 2\d\d/) { exit 0; } else { exit 1; }'
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like you work for Questdb. Can I ask few more detailed questions for app I am trying to build for algo trading? Is there any dedicated forum or support slack for devs ?

Comment: You are welcome. There is a community slack at https://slack.questdb.io/. Otherwise you can also keep posting on stackoverflow with the #questdb tag and the core team should see it